# If $y>0$, prove that $|\cot(x+iy)+i| < \frac{e^{-2y}}{1-e^{-2y}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $y>0$, prove that 
$$|\cot(x+iy)+i| < \frac{e^{-2y}}{1-e^{-2y}}$$

I'm new on this. By now I got this

$$\cot(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}.\frac{2i}{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}} = \frac{(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})i}{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}$$

From here I got no idea what to do.

Comment: from there you add $i$...........

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\cot(x+iy)={\frac {-1-i{\rm coth} \left(y\right)\cot \left( x \right) }{-i
{\rm coth} \left(y\right)+\cot \left( x \right) }}
$$